# Quintus Game Development

Tags: html, quintus

I am trying to pause between levels in this game but the pause feature wont work. Any help would be great. Currently the code just keeps getting stuck in a loop and prints out Next Level.

The level system is supposed to work when this.p.levelData.nextLevel is true but it keeps looping.

Any help would be great.

```
                Quintus.ZombiesGameplay = function(Q) {

                //game level
                Q.Sprite.extend('Level', {
                  init: function(p) {
                      this._super(p, { 
                        asset: '/assets/images/background.png',
                        type: Q.SPRITE_GROUND,
                        x: 90 + 1024/2,
                        y: 768/2,
                        w: 1024,
                        h: 768,
                        sunFrequency: {min: 3,max: 10}, //min and max number of seconds for sun to appear   
                      });

                      this.timeNextSun = this.getTimeNextSun(); //time for the next sun to appear

                      //level data
                      this.zombieIndex = 0; //current index from zombies array
                      this.numZombies = this.p.levelData.zombies.length;
                      this.levelTime = 0; //keep track of the level duration

                      //save the position of each plant in a grid
                      this.plantsGrid = new Array(new Array(7), new Array(7), new Array(7), new Array(7), new Array(7), new Array(7));

                      this.on('touch');

                      Q.audio.play('/assets/audio/ZombiesOnYourLawn.mp3');
                  },
                  step: function(dt) {
                    //update level duration
                    this.levelTime += dt;

                    //check for level passed
                    if(this.p.levelData.duration < this.levelTime) {
                      if(this.p.levelData.nextLevel) {
                        // Q.stageScene("level", {levelData: Q.assets[this.p.levelData.nextLevel]});
                        // Q.stage().pause();
                        // Q.stage().unpause();
                        // debugger;
                        nextLevel();
                        // pauseGame();
                        // unPauseGame();
                      }else {
                        endGame();
                        // Q.stageScene('level', {levelData: Q.assets['/assets/data/level1.json']});
                        // Q.stage().pause();
                        // Q.stage().unpause();

                      } 
                    }

                    //create zombies at the defined times
                    if(this.zombieIndex < this.numZombies) {

                      var currentZombie = this.p.levelData.zombies[this.zombieIndex];
                      if(this.levelTime >= currentZombie.time) {    
                        var zombieData = Q.zombieTypes[currentZombie.type];     
                        var newZombie = new Q.Zombie(
                          Q._extend(zombieData, {y: currentZombie.row * 120 + 60})
                        );                 
                        this.stage.insert(newZombie);

                        this.zombieIndex++;
                      }
                    }               

                    //update sun generation timing
                    this.timeNextSun -= dt;
                    if(this.timeNextSun <= 0) {
                      this.timeNextSun = this.getTimeNextSun();

                      //create sun in the sun stage
                      Q.stage(1).insert(new Q.Sun());
                    }
                  },
                  touch: function(touch) {
                    //if a plant is selected
                    if(Q.state.get('currentPlant')) {
                      //get plantsGrid coordinates
                      var row = Math.floor((touch.y)/120);
                      var col = Math.floor((touch.x - 240)/120);

                      if(row >= 0 && row < this.plantsGrid.length && col >= 0 && col < this.plantsGrid[0].length) {
                        if(!this.plantsGrid[row][col] && Q.state.get('sun') >= Q.state.get('currentPlant').cost) {
                          Q.state.dec('sun', Q.state.get('currentPlant').cost);
                          var newPlant = new Q.Plant(Q._extend({x: 240 + 60 + col*120, y: 60 + row*120}, Q.state.get('currentPlant')));
                          this.stage.insert(newPlant);
                          this.plantsGrid[row][col] = newPlant;
                          newPlant.p.gridRow = row;
                          newPlant.p.gridCol = col;
                        }
                      }
                    }            
                  },
                  getTimeNextSun: function() {
                    return this.p.sunFrequency.min + Math.random()*(this.p.sunFrequency.max - this.p.sunFrequency.min);
                  },
                });
              }

              function nextLevel(){
                console.log('NEXT LEVEL');

                Q.stageScene("nextLevel",1, { label: "LEVEL COMPLETED!" });

                Q.scene('nextLevel',function(stage) {
                  var container = stage.insert(new Q.UI.Container({
                    x: Q.width/2, y: Q.height/2, fill: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
                  }));

                  var nextLevelButton = container.insert(new Q.UI.Button({ x: 0, y: 0, fill: "#CCCCCC",
                                                                  label: "Next Level" }))         
                  var label = container.insert(new Q.UI.Text({x:10, y: -10 - nextLevelButton.p.h, fill: "#FFFFFF", 
                                                                   label: stage.options.label }));
                  nextLevelButton.on("click",function() {
                    alert("test");
                    Q.stageScene("level", {levelData: Q.assets[this.p.levelData.nextLevel] });
                  });
                  container.fit(20);
                });
                pauseGame();
              };

              function endGame(){
                console.log('YOU WON!');

                Q.stageScene("endGame",1, { label: "You Have Won The Game!" });

                Q.scene('endGame',function(stage) {
                  var container = stage.insert(new Q.UI.Container({
                    x: Q.width/2, y: Q.height/2, fill: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
                  }));

                  var button = container.insert(new Q.UI.Button({ x: 0, y: 0, fill: "#CCCCCC",
                                                                  label: "Play Again" }))         
                  var label = container.insert(new Q.UI.Text({x:10, y: -10 - button.p.h, fill: "#FFFFFF", 
                                                                   label: stage.options.label }));
                  button.on("click",function() {
                    Q.clearStages();
                    Q.stageScene('level', {levelData: Q.assets['/assets/data/level1.json']});
                  });
                  container.fit(20);
                });
                // pauseGame();
              };

              function pauseGame(){
                console.log("Game Paused");
                Q.stage().pause()
              };

              function unPauseGame(){
                Q.stage().unpause()
              };
```